# Scheme - syntax with if statements

Tags: scheme, racket

Can anyone explain why this isn't working? I am following the documentation and I cannot understand why I get an error:

```
 (define (functionName n)
    (if (n < 10)   ;;if condition
         1   ;; then condition
         3)) ;; else condition
```

I get the error:

```
 application: not a procedure;
  expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
   given: 5
   arguments...:
    #<procedure:<>
    10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this in two ways. Your code is correct and you just called it wrong (bad type for `n`) or your code was accidentally written in infix notation. I'll illustrate both:

**Passed wrong argument**

`n` can be any data type and it can even be a procedure and if it is there is nothing wrong with your code:

```
(define (compare-15 predicate-procedure argument)
  (predicate-procedure 15 argument))

(define (compare-2 predicate-procedure argument)
  (predicate-procedure 2 argument))

(functionName compare-15) ; ==> 3
(functionName compare-2)  ; ==> 1
```

What happens is that your procedure is calling the supplied procedure with a procedure for comparing `<` and an argument.

**Accidental infix**

Algol programmers are used to prefix `fun( expr )` and infix `x cmp y` while in LISP dialects all those have one common form and that is prefix all the way: `(fun expr)` and `(cmd x y)`.

```
(define (function-name n)
  (if (< n 10)          ;; predicate expression
      1                 ;; consequent expression
      3))               ;; alternative expression

(function-name 15) ; ==> 3
(function-name 2)  ; ==> 1
```

Since Scheme can have functions as argument, meaning every argument can be put in the first position, it might be exactly what you wanted and Scheme doesn't know until it gets a number to be called as a procedure that something is wrong.

The error message is quite clear when you know that every procedure call is called application. It expected to call a procedure but behind the variable `n` there was a number. "expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments. given: 5" probably makes more sense now?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(define (functionName n)
  (if (< n 10)
      1 
      3))
```

Remember: Scheme uses *prefix* notation, meaning that all operators must go *before* the operands. In other words, this is wrong: `(n < 10)`, and this is correct: `(< n 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

The function should be the first thing in the `if` (scheme uses prefix notation, not infix).

```
(define (functionName n)
    (if (< n 10)   ;;if condition
        1   ;; then condition
        3)) ;; else condition
```

Then

```
(functionName 2)
```

Outputs

```
1
```

when I run it in Chicken Scheme.